# Click event not firing on label in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I have created a click handler on a gwt label, but it fails to fire. Whats wrong? Same method works for other widgets like icon etc.

```
 @UiField Label fileName;
 ---
 ---
public void addClickHandler() {
    fileName.sinkEvents(Event.ONCLICK);



    handler = this.addHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            Window.alert("UI clicked");


        }
    }, ClickEvent.getType());

}
```

Comment: its firing and you are killing it at `event.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: its registering but not firing. yes, the parent also has a click event I don't want this event to bubble and fire the parent.

Comment: Are you getting a breakpoint at `event.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: not hitting event.preventDefault();

Comment: what is `this`?  you are adding native event handler to `this` but you calling `sinkEvents` on your label. I think that might be a reason

Comment: Expecting that label is not your root element, where do you register your ClickEvent? I would expect something like that: fileName.addClickHandler(...);

Comment: @user902383 Thanks! That was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in comment. Reason why it is not working is because you are adding native event handler to `this`, and as i but you need to sink DOM events on element to be able to handle them. As you did not do this for `this` element but for `Label` it won't work.

As You want to handle click element on `Label`, you need to add your handler to `fileName` and that will work